# Graph API to subscribe to a user (similar to Subscribe button social plugin)

Tags: facebook, subscription

is there a call in the Graph API that would allow my Facebook app to subscribe a user to another user. The same action Subscribe button would do or the user would do himself on someone's profile page.
I know I can list users, which the authenticated user is subscribed to, but can I make a new subscription?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found so far [follow action](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/follows/)
If I'll have any new finds I will update here

EDIT:
this is a dead end as far as SDK 3.1.1
see [How to make a user subscribe to another users using Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568909/how-to-make-a-user-subscribe-to-another-users-using-graph-api)