# How to make a user subscribe to another users using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to users when added to this website they automatically subscribe to another users in facebook. I know I can list users, which the authenticated user is subscribed to, but can I make a new subscription?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at docs,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribedto

Graph api gives only 'read' action for both `subscribers` and `subscribedto`

However, you can use the [Subscribe Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) plugin

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can use subscribe button for your need :)